# Latency priority changes being applied to a thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, thread-priority

I would like to write a program, where several worker threads should process different tasks with different priorities. Large tasks would be processed with low priority and small tasks with a very high priority.

In a perfect world I would simply set a different priority for each kind of task, but since it is more task types than priority levels available on Windows, I think i have to set the thread priorities dynamically.

I think there should be a main thread with highest priority, working as a kind of scheduler setting the priorities of the worker threads dynamically. But I wonder what actually happens on Windows, when I call SetThreadPriority() and especially how quick the priority change is taken into account by the OS.

Ideally I need to boost the priority of a 'small task thread' within < 1 ms. Is this possible? And is there any way to change the latency of the OS (if there is any) reacting on the priority change?

Comment: Obviously I don't know very much about multithreading and scheduling. I'm aware of the basic concepts (round-robin, base priorities, priority classes, etc) but I'd love to get more insights into 'what happens when' and the timing of schedulers and priority changes.

I'm happy about any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The windows dispatcher (scheduler) is not a single process/thread; it is spread across the kernel. The dispatcher is generally triggered by the following events:

1. Thread becomes ready for execution
2. Thread leaves running state (e.g. quantum expires, wait state, or done)
3. The thread's priority changes (e.g. `SetThreadPriority`)
4. Processor affinity changes

*I need to boost the priority of a 'small task thread' within < 1 ms. Is this possible?*

According to 3: **Yes**, the dispatcher will reschedule immediately.

Ref.: [Windows Internals Tour: Windows Processes, Threads and
Memory](http://www.dmi.unict.it/diraimondo/web/wp-content/uploads/classes/so/1011/Windows-Process-Theads-and-Memory.pdf), *Microsoft Academic Club 2011*

Comment: thank you very much! i did some tests which confirm especially 3. which helps a lot.